# does jQuery outerWidth() includes css outline?

Tags: jquery

Surprisingly enough, I couldn't  find an answer to this question in [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/).

I do understand, according to the outline [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/outline) that

> Outlines do not take up space, they are drawn above the content

But still, I'm getting confused by seeing different results of elements width when playing with the outline.

Comment: You'd have to demo the *"different results"* for us to know what you are referring to.

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks, I would've done that, but bu the time I got the first answer I already understood my bug was a result of a different issue (angular directives priority)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple test shows this is not the case. jquery versions 1,2,3 all do not take this into account - the `outerWidth()` remains the same for varying `outline`s:

```js
$('.outlined').text(function() { return $(this).outerWidth(); })
```

```css
.outlined {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid #f00;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.outlined:nth-child(2) { outline: 2px solid #000; }
.outlined:nth-child(3) { outline: 3px solid #333; }
.outlined:nth-child(4) { outline: 4px solid #666; }
.outlined:nth-child(5) { outline: 5px solid #999; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="outlined"></div>
  <div class="outlined"></div>
  <div class="outlined"></div>
  <div class="outlined"></div>
  <div class="outlined"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The outline is applied above the border rule. So, the outerWidth() doesn't include the outline for its computation as we can see from the jQuery docs:

> Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding and border.

There is no mention about outline.

So, to calculate the width including the outline, you need to explicitly add it:

```
parseFloat($(elem).outerWidth())+parseFloat($(elem).css('outline-width'));
```

**Note:** Even if you decide to take the elements width including margin, you wouldn't get the outline-width value by just using `outerWidth(true)`. You need to add outline-width manually.

Answer (score 0):

No, jquery function .outerWidth() doesn't include css outline and margin property.It includes Padding & Border css properties.